# react-datepicker highlighting date ranges in other months

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker and noticed that when using date ranges, dates in any month that is not the current month is highlighted based on the selected startDate and endDate. How do I remove this?[image]

Comment: Don't use images to show your code, please write the code in your question. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have a same problem with you, when hovering will have class name "react-datepicker__day--in-selecting-range", I need class remove when not hover date. Add custom classname dont resolve the problem. Do you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to style it with CSS.

From inspecting their datepicker, looks like you can target outside-month days with `.react-datepicker__day--outside-month`.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
disabledKeyboardNavigation
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.